# Помогите составить регулярку PHP

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка:

```
<div style="float:left;max-width:280px;"><a href="/url.htm" alt="Операция
```

Нужно получить:

```
/url.htm
```

---

**Дополнительный вопрос:**

В зеннопостере есть конструктор регулярных выражений. Выражение в нем для данной ситуации выглядит так:

```
(?<=\ \ <div\ style="float:left;max-width:280px;"><a\ href=").*(?="\ alt)
```

Как написать такое же, только для php?

Я новичок в PHP, поэтому только начал разбираться в этом.

Comment: Используйте htmldom для этого а не регулярку

Answer (score 2):

$html - строка, которую разбираем, $m - результаты

```
preg_match_all('#href="(.*?)"#us', $html, $m);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
preg_match('#<\s?a\s+href=["']([^"']*)["']#ui', $data, $result);
```

Вариант слегка упоротый, но иногда попадаются упоротые вёрстки

Comment: Ваш вариант слегка кривой. Про символьные классы прочитайте https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%E5%E3%F3%EB%FF%F0%ED%FB%E5_%E2%FB%F0%E0%E6%E5%ED%E8%FF#.D0.A1.D0.B8.D0.BC.D0.B2.D0.BE.D0.BB.D1.8C.D0.BD.D1.8B.D0.B5_.D0.BA.D0.BB.D0.B0.D1.81.D1.81.D1.8B_.28.D0.BD.D0.B0.D0.B1.D0.BE.D1.80.D1.8B_.D1.81.D0.B8.D0.BC.D0.B2.D0.BE.D0.BB.D0.BE.D0.B2.29

Comment: Visman, да, вы правы. убрал "палки"....надеюсь имелось в виду это

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = '<div style="float:left;max-width:280px;"><a href="/url.htm" alt="Операция';
$pattern = '~href="(.*)" ~';
preg_match($pattern, $data, $out);
print_r($out[1]);
```

инструкция тут

[http://php.net/manual/ru/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html)

или тут
http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html

Comment: Чуть-чуть дополним строку справа и получим в ответ `/url.htm" alt="Операция` http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f8bc2b2825f50b4d8914931cce474e3858d72c4b

Comment: $pattern = '~href="(.*?)"~';

Comment: А если результат не один на странице, то как получить несколько штук в разные переменные?

Comment: Изменил чуть под себя и регулярка работает с целой HTML страницей. Все гуд. Только вот мучаюсь, чтобы несколько результатов получить.

Comment: для всех одноименных тагов со страницы можно использовать `preg_match_all('~<'.$tag.'>(.*)</'.$tag.'>~', $data, $out, PREG_SET_ORDER);`